# In Swift, if a background queue sets up the values of a bunch of class properties (singletons etc), afterwards will the main thread see those changes?

Tags: swift, multithreading

In Swift, if a background queue initializes and sets up a bunch of instances of various classes, then assigns them to static/class properties (singletons etc), afterwards will the main thread see those changes?

I'm generally aware that each thread has its own stack allocation, presumably for use for local variables and stuff that's only known to the thread that's using it.

But I would think when it comes to any property of any type that *could be* used by another thread then it would be the same memory used across both threads.

Is that incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: Static properties on type, and global variables are all globally visible. However, accessing them from one thread while writing to another can cause data races, so you need to wrap accesses in a locking mechanism. Honestly, Apple pushes devs towards singletons way too strongly. You should really try to avoid them.

Comment: @Alexander I have never felt that Apple was "pushing" me towards singletons. I never once heard them say, "We recommend to use the singleton pattern" or similar. Lately they've been pushing SwiftUI, which enables us to completely avoid mutable global state. Granted it doesn't stop you from having a singleton as your "observableObject" but you have to make that decision consciously—Apple can't be held responsible for that. That being said I am working on an app whose legacy code features way too many singletons... and we aim to fix that, but have to deal with it for now.

Comment: Welp, I have  Mainly from all the code examples, which make really heavy use of them, mainly to simplify the code that isn't pertinent to the feature they're trying to focus on.